# FileReader.result is not assignable to type img 'src'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building image uploader in my website using React.js and typescript.

I'm trying read files from input through `FileReader` and  set the react state named 'thumb' with `FileReader.result`.

the problem is state `thumb` type is not assignable to `<img src={thumb}/>`

How can I determine thumb state properly?

```
Type 'string | ArrayBuffer | null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.
```

also, alt also complains this

```
Type 'Blob' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

```
import React, { FC, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

interface IImageReaderProps {
  name: string;
}
const ImageReader: FC<IImageReaderProps> = () => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [thumb, setThumb] = useState<string | ArrayBuffer | null>("");
  const fileRef = useRef<Blob>(new Blob([], { type: "image/png" }));
  const handleReader = () => {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    fileReader.onloadend = () => {
      setIsLoading(false);
      setThumb(fileReader.result);
    };

    fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileRef.current);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (fileRef !== name) {
      handleReader();
    }
  }, [thumb]);

  if (isLoading) {
    return <p>...loading</p>;
  }

  return <img src={thumb} alt={fileRef.current} />; // <- this shows error 
};
```

Comment: You could look at [FileReader.readAsDataUrl()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

Comment: @JacobSmit I already read this reference, want to get more proper type descriptions here.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xscp9r?file=index.js) help at all, I don't understand what you are attempting to achieve with your fileRef or name variables.

Comment: @JacobSmit    Thank you for your link, but I already mentioned above that this is all about  type matters when implement with typescript. And What you gave me is totally javascript files and no typescript.

Comment: Converted to typescript: [https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2mbg1w](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-2mbg1w)

Comment: Assume your issue was that `FileReader.result` is used when going from Blob -> string using `FileReader.readAsDataUrl()` and from Blob -> ArrayBuffer using `FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer()`. This means that it is typed to both string and ArrayBuffer, for your use you can just ignore when ever its an array buffer (which should be never).